# Convert an SVG-path to polygons for use within Javascript Clipper

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to perform Boolean Operations on SVG Paths (that contain beziers, both quadratic and cubic) using [JS Clipper](https://sourceforge.net/p/jsclipper/wiki/Home%206/0).

[JS Clipper](https://sourceforge.net/p/jsclipper/wiki/Home%206/0) starts with polygons then performs the operation and then it seems to convert them back to SVG paths.

The function below gives an SVG path but the below example starts with 2 polygons.

An example function:

```
// Polygon Arrays are expanded for better readability

function clip() {
  var subj_polygons = [
    [{
      X: 10,
      Y: 10
    }, {
      X: 110,
      Y: 10
    }, {
      X: 110,
      Y: 110
    }, {
      X: 10,
      Y: 110
    }],
    [{
      X: 20,
      Y: 20
    }, {
      X: 20,
      Y: 100
    }, {
      X: 100,
      Y: 100
    }, {
      X: 100,
      Y: 20
    }]
  ];

  var clip_polygons = [
    [{
      X: 50,
      Y: 50
    }, {
      X: 150,
      Y: 50
    }, {
      X: 150,
      Y: 150
    }, {
      X: 50,
      Y: 150
    }],
    [{
      X: 60,
      Y: 60
    }, {
      X: 60,
      Y: 140
    }, {
      X: 140,
      Y: 140
    }, {
      X: 140,
      Y: 60
    }]
  ];

  var scale = 100;
  subj_polygons = scaleup(subj_polygons, scale);
  clip_polygons = scaleup(clip_polygons, scale);

  var cpr = new ClipperLib.Clipper();
  cpr.AddPolygons(subj_polygons, ClipperLib.PolyType.ptSubject);
  cpr.AddPolygons(clip_polygons, ClipperLib.PolyType.ptClip);

  var subject_fillType = ClipperLib.PolyFillType.pftNonZero;
  var clip_fillType = ClipperLib.PolyFillType.pftNonZero;
  var clipTypes = [ClipperLib.ClipType.ctUnion];
  var clipTypesTexts = "Union";
  var solution_polygons, svg, cont = document.getElementById('svgcontainer');

  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < clipTypes.length; i++) {
    solution_polygons = new ClipperLib.Polygons();
    cpr.Execute(clipTypes[i], solution_polygons, subject_fillType, clip_fillType);
    console.log(polys2path(solution_polygons, scale));
  }

}

// helper function to scale up polygon coordinates
function scaleup(poly, scale) {
  var i, j;
  if (!scale) scale = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < poly.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < poly[i].length; j++) {
      poly[i][j].X *= scale;
      poly[i][j].Y *= scale;
    }
  }
  return poly;
}

// converts polygons to SVG path string
function polys2path(poly, scale) {
  var path = "",
    i, j;
  if (!scale) scale = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < poly.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < poly[i].length; j++) {
      if (!j) path += "M";
      else path += "L";
      path += (poly[i][j].X / scale) + ", " + (poly[i][j].Y / scale);
    }
    path += "Z";
  }
  return path;

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that you mean some sort of svg path to polygon conversion.

I have searched a lot, but not found anything reliable and out-of-the-box solution.

SVG path can consist of ten different segment, or 20 if we take into account both relative and absolute coordinates. They are represented as letters in path element's d-attribute: relative ones are `mhvlcqastz` and absolute ones are `MHVLCQASTZ`. Each have different attributes, `a` (elliptical arc) being the most complicated one. The most usable and flexible of types is `c` (cubic bezier curve), because it can represent all other types in rather high precision as these examples show: http://jsbin.com/oqojan/32, http://jsbin.com/oqojan/42.

Raphael JS library has `Path2Curve`-function which can convert all path segments to cubic curves and it can handle also the complicated arc to cubic conversion. Unfortunately it has a bug, so that it cannot handle all possible path segment combinations, but fortunately there is a fixed version of library available: http://jsbin.com/oqojan/32/edit (look at the Javascript-window).

When all path segments are converted to cubic curves, they can be converted to individual line segments. There are few ways, and the best seems to be [an adaptive recursive subdivision method](http://antigrain.com/research/adaptive_bezier/), which produces more line segments in sharp turns of curve and fewer in other parts of curve to achieve a balance of curve fidelity and low count of segments to maximize rendering speed, but unfortunately it could not handle all collinear cases. I succeeded in converting AntiGrain's method to Javascript and added presplitting functionality, which splits the curve in local extremes (first derivative roots) and after that the AntiGrain method handles also all possible collinear cases:

Collinear horizontal: http://jsbin.com/ivomiq/6
Set of different cases: http://jsbin.com/ivomiq/7
Random: http://jsbin.com/ivomiq/8
Collinear rotated: http://jsbin.com/ivomiq/9

All the above samples have two paths in top of each other to show possible errors in adaptive algorithm: the red curve is splitted using very slow brute force method and the green one is splitted using AntiGrain method. If you see not red at all, the AntiGrain's method `approximate()-function` is working as expected.

OK, now we have repaired Raphael and repaired AntiGrain. If we combine these both methods, we can create a function that converts ANY svg path element to polygon (single or multiple subpolygons). I'm not 100% sure that this is the best or fastest method, but it should be usable. Of course the best would be native browser implementation...

Comment: Would this solution work for ANY shape no matter how complex? I've dropped trying to use your library due to the path to polygon conversion. I did actually managed to use this method from Phrogz: https://gist.github.com/Phrogz/845901 to convert to polygons with only one big problem. My users are supposed to draw very,very complex curvy shapes that must be boolean operated on, WITHOUT LOSS of fidelity on any curves. This requires over 800 sampling required for polygonizing which doesnt even work in most cases with Phrogz solution. Do you believe the Raphael+AG will work far better?

Comment: My solution is for svg-paths only, so you need to first convert other shapes to paths (see: https://github.com/johan/svg-js-utils/blob/master/paths.js, pathify() -function). I think the conversion quality is very good (because you can adjust the precision using angle threshold and also overall scaling parameter) using the solution I suggested. And I have tested also Phrogz's solution, which is typical brute force method and it is slow when shapes are complex and produces easily too much or too little points. Antigrain solution produces optimal count of points. What is AG?

Comment: I can try to help if I see enough of your code. You can reach me using timo.roskapostiREMOVETHIS@hotmail.com. Maybe better that we continue this discussion via email, and when the solution is found, to post the required steps or functions here.

Comment: It was a typing mistake a i guess(shapes meaning paths). I meant that my users are supposed to draw really complex curvy paths not shapes. Regarding Phrogz brute force it is very slow indeed.

Comment: I just did send you an email, did  i use the correct address??

Comment: Yes, the address was correct and I received your email. Let's see if we can find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [De Casteljau's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau%27s_algorithm) to break `bezier curve` into smaller straight lines, and join them to create `polygon`.

Here is some references of `De Casteljau's algorithm`

- http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/Bezier/de-casteljau.html
- http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/Bezier/de-casteljau.html