# SVG - get the difference path of two paths

Tags: c#, javascript, svg

Is there an easy way to get the difference path of two SVG paths? I have a large polygon where I need to cut some holes from or which I have to cut into pieces by subtracting a path.

Preferably something in JavaScript, but C# would also work.

I've already searched for solutions. The closest is [How can I cut one shape from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983256/how-can-i-cut-one-shape-from-another), but it is about shapes, not paths. And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1983432/1634286) gives just a clue how to draw a path with holes but no way to automate this.

Am I really stuck with manually adding the second path (including all the stuff like checking the direction, absolute/relative position, transforms etc)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not very sure, what you want to achieve, but I can see two possibilities: A) draw a polygon with holes or B) make boolean difference operation between two polygons.

### A) DRAW POLYGON WITH HOLES

The winding order is the key. If you have outer polygon (SVG path), which is clockwise (CW) like this:

`"M155,61.67 L155,212.7 L288.98,212.7 L288.98,61.67 L173.01999999999998,61.67 L155,61.67Z"`

and a hole polygon (SVG path) which is counter-clockwise (CCW), like this:
`"M274.37,190.77 L171.24,190.77 L171.24,81.16 L274.37,81.16 L274.37,81.16 L274.37,190.77Z"`

And you combine these into same path:

`"M155,61.67 L155,212.7 L288.98,212.7 L288.98,61.67 L173.01999999999998,61.67 L155,61.67ZM274.37,190.77 L171.24,190.77 L171.24,81.16 L274.37,81.16 L274.37,81.16 L274.37,190.77Z"`

you get the following polygon with hole:

[image]

In the above image it seems that inner polygon is subtracted from the outer polygon.

### B) MAKE BOOLEAN DIFFERENCE OPERATION BETWEEN TWO POLYGONS

If you want to cut one polygon from other polygon and want to create a new geometry by making a boolean difference operation between two or more polygons, you can use [JAVASCRIPT CLIPPER](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsclipper/), which has [AN ONLINE DEMO](http://jsclipper.sourceforge.net/5.0.2.2/main_demo.html), where you can play with different boolean operations. You can also input your own polygons by clicking Polygons - Custom. You can input them using SVG path syntax (only MoveTo:s and LineTo:s are permitted). There is also a Polygon Explorer, where you can see the result of operations. Also outputs can be seen as SVG paths. There is also [A WIKI PAGE](https://sourceforge.net/p/jsclipper/wiki/Home/), which has code examples.

An example of Subject ("polygon") and Clip ("clipping") polygons:
[image]

Boolean Difference between Subject and Clip polygons:
[image]

Comment: what I was looking for was B) boolean difference. clipper looks promising, thanks.

Comment: Here is some information that you may need: flattening transformations (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13102801/1691517) and polygonizing paths ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247711/convert-an-svg-path-to-polygons-for-use-within-javascript-clipper). I have made an out-of-the-box solution that combines all that is needed, but it's rather complicated solution. Few weeks ago there appeared a new better solution, in which I'm working on.

Comment: This solution **does** work, although not in every case (I'm not sure why). If you add the attribute `fill-rule="evenodd"` to the path it starts behaving consistently (aka it works).